# Filling missing values with distribution

Tags: time-series, missing-data

So i have 2 dataset.

On the first one i have values for each hour of a day. Example:

```
Date                 Value
05/07/2017 01:00     5
05/07/2017 02:00     10
05/07/2017 03:00     5
```

In the second dataset i only have the total of each day

```
Date                 Value
05/07/2017           40
```

So i want to distribute the total of the second dataset by the same distribution of the first dataset. Something like this:

```
Date                 Value
05/07/2017 01:00     10
05/07/2017 02:00     20
05/07/2017 03:00     10
```

How can i do this? I'm using R and created a time series for the first dataset.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the `mice` package for R which specialises in missing data imputation. In your case probably a knn method which would impute the missing values by regarding similar (times) attribute-wise samples might do the trick.

Having a second look, maybe a bit more sophisticated procedure would be possible to bootstrap the values across the different times and then to fill the missing value you would have to find a random (times) combination (assuming that you use a random sample of each time specific time pool or distribution) of these which would total to the sum that you have.

Comment: Can you give some insights for i looking for?

Comment: Sorry what would you mean by insights? which methodology seems more appealing to you?

Comment: if i understood right, i think the first one, because the first data have a pattern that repeats every day.

Comment: Cool, so what you can do is to train a knn(n=1) Classifier with the samples that do contain the 'Value' and as a test set you can set the samples with the missing Data and the 'Value' as the target variable. In that way your Classifier will label the missing Data with the most appropriate time.

Comment: Please specify if the answer is suitable for you, if yes please accept it.

Comment: Yeah i will try to do this! Thanks!